# Iterating over the keys of a python dictionary, when keys are integers, I get this error, "TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable"

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary, while-loop

I am working on `pay raise` of `employees` with particular `ids`. Suppose, I have `5` employees in my company. I have shown them in a `employee_id_list`. I want python to take input from me which consists of the particular `ids` of the `employees`, I want to raise the pay, along with their `salary`. Then, I am creating the `dictionary` out of these inputs. Now I want to iterate over the `employee_id_list` such that it matches with of the `input ids`. If it matches, I want to take the respective `value of key` which is `salary` and raise the pay. But I am getting an error.
I have searched for everything present on stackoverflow but nothing matches my problem

```
employee_id_list = [27, 25, 98, 78, 66]
employee_dict = dict()
while True:
    x = input("Enter an key to continue and 'r' for result: ").lower()
    if x== 'r':
        break
    try:
        employee_id = int(input("Enter key the Employee id: ")) 
        salary = int(input(f"Enter the {employee_id}'s salary: "))
        employee_dict[employee_id] = salary
    except ValueError:
        print("Please Enter the Integers!")
        continue 
print(employee_dict)
for e_ids in employee_id_list:
    for key, value in employee_dict.items():
        if e_ids in employee_dict[key] :
            employee_dict[value] = 0.8*value + value
print(employee_dict)
```

I am getting this error

```
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the correct ideas of @Konny and @Sunderam together, and adding my own change for checking if statement, the answer is:

```py
employee_id_list = [27, 25, 98, 78, 66]
    employee_dict = dict()

    while True:
        x = input("Enter an key to continue and 'r' for result: ").lower()
        if x== 'r':
            break
        try:
            employee_id = int(input("Enter key the Employee id: "))
            salary = int(input(f"Enter the {employee_id}'s salary: "))
            employee_dict[employee_id] = salary
        except ValueError:
            print("Please Enter the Integers!")
            continue

    print(employee_dict)
    for e_ids in employee_id_list:
        for key, value in employee_dict.items():
            if e_ids == key:    # This is my contribution
                employee_dict[key] = 1.8*value
    print(employee_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's this:

```
if e_ids in employee_dict[key] :
```

`employee_dict` is a dictionary of string-integer pairs, and you are trying to check whether `e_ids` is in `employee_dict[key]`, which is an `int`, not an iterable like a list, where you can check if an element is contained in it.

Also, don't you mean `employee_dict[key] = 0.8*value + value`?

Comment: You are right. I changed exactly like that but my error doesn't go away

Answer (score 1):

You confused with `key` and `value` variable of for loop

Try this:

```
employee_id_list = [27, 25, 98, 78, 66]
employee_dict = dict()
while True:
    x = input("Enter an key to continue and 'r' for result: ").lower()
    if x == 'r':
        break
    try:
        employee_id = int(input("Enter key the Employee id: "))
        salary = int(input(f"Enter the {employee_id}'s salary: "))
        employee_dict[employee_id] = salary
    except ValueError:
        print("Please Enter the Integers!")
        continue
for e_ids in employee_id_list:
    for key, value in employee_dict.items():
        if e_ids in employee_dict:
            employee_dict[key] = 0.8*value + value
print(employee_dict)
```

You have to write `employee_dict[key] = 0.8*value+value` rather than `employee_dict[value] = 0.8*value+value`.

You can also write `employee_dict[key] = value*1.8` rather than `employee_dict[key] = 0.8*value+value`.

Comment: Yes you are right but error is still there

Comment: Thanks for contributing, It is more than enough. I was not able to figure out this ```employee_dict[key] = value*1.8```